# sortBy and sortByDesc $balance problem in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel

I am using sortBy in a loop on the Laravel blade and added a balance column. This column calculates the balance at the end of each line. There is no problem at this point. But when I do sortByDesc I get irrelevant results.

I will be glad if you can help :)

```
            @php
                $balance = 0;
            @endphp
            @foreach($transactions->sortByDesc('created_at') as $transaction)
                <tr data-id="{{ $transaction->id }}"
                    data-click-url="{{ $transaction->action_type == 'stock_delivery' ? route('admin.expenses.deliveries.show',$transaction->action_id) : mRoute('edit', $transaction->id) }}">
                    <td>{{ date('d.m.Y', strtotime($transaction->paid_at)) }}</td>
                    <td>@transUcFirst('generic.financial.payment_types.' .
                        PAYMENT_TYPE[$transaction->payment_type])
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if($transaction->action_type)
                            @if($transaction->action_type == 'sale')
                                <span class="text-danger">@transUcFirst('generic.financial.sale')</span>
                            @elseif($transaction->action_type == 'stock_delivery')
                                @trans('models.delivery.delivery_invoice')
                            @elseif($transaction->action_type == 'subscription')
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <span class="text-success">Tahsilat</span>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">@currencySymbol <b>{{ tl_format($transaction->amount) }}</b></td>
                    <td class="text-right">@currencySymbol {{ tl_format($balance += $transaction->amount) }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

[it is normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAQUP.jpg)

[using sortByDesc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zytSp.jpg)

Comment: By looping over the data in reverse order, you have inverted your calculation logic at the same time. If you still want to get the same _values_ in each row, and only have the rows sorted in reverse order - then you need to loop your data set in the original order first, do your calculation (and store the result for each row somewhere/somehow), and then output it all in reverse order afterwards ...

Comment: If I understand correctly, I guess I will send the result to the view after I do the operation in the controller?

Comment: That would make the most sense, yes.